# How to suppress script errors on internet explorer 7 coming from an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, c++, iframe, webbrowser-control

I built a dll with c++. Inside it I included cwebpage.dll which is using Microsoft Internet Explorer Version 7.0 as standart, with the following user agent:

```
Mozila/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Tridnet/7.0;
.NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 
3.5.30729)
```

The following line in the webpage I show, pops up a script error.

```
<iframe id="stream" src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=example"></iframe>
```

The error is presented in a popup alert form, just like shown in the following screenshot.

[image: Script Error]

I've searched a lot for disabling that error, but I guess that since it's coming from an iframe, javascript sulotions like

```
window.onerror = null;
```

or

```
window.onerror=function(){return true;}
```

are not working and the script errors are still appearing.

I found how to disable it from the internet explorer settings which is not what I'm looking for.
It has to be a generic solution for all my dll users.
I have also tried to edit the IE debugging disabling registry values to "yes" on

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main

Values: Disable Script Debugger/DisableScriptDebuggerIE
```

but I didn't see any effect. The script errors are still appearing.

How to prevent this error from appearing on one hand, but let the scripts to be continued on the other? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you creating this iFrame via script. What other scripts are/should be running? Which version(s) of IE all or up to version X. Please edit your question.

Comment: @Codebreaker007 The exact version has been added. No other scripts are running, it's just the iFrame code line. In addition, I tried any possible content with the following meta tag: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", however errors always appear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Youtube and facebook for instance do not allow their sites to be displayed in an iframe. So the error is thrown by cloudfront scripts (either ddos protection or trying to block your request) - so how to solve - add

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
   window.onerror = function (e) { return true; }        
</script>
```

to the header of every page/application that you pull in via the iFrames, as well as to the parent page.

Position of the Script. Before all other scripts (like jQuery and MicrosoftAjax or calling player.twitch.tv) Those scripts might throw errors before the window.onerror script was even evaluated.

The iFrame errors seem to bubble up regardless of the error handling on the parent page. So go into your code repository and make the necessary changes to each of the applications you pull in. 
[More information on embedding twitch in iFrames](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/embed/video-and-clips)

Comment: I don't have an access to Twitch pages, this is an external website. This is the reason for why I use iFrame. Putting that code block in the page that using the iFrame isn't resloving the error as mentioned in the thread, http://prntscr.com/rt4q6h - the error is still appearing.

Comment: I know that twitch is external but you are working with IE7 because you use NET4 as your user agent shows so you seem to run some application which you have access to. Thats what I wrote above. The main page alone is not sufficient!

Comment: I tried to use the php function file_get_contents and modify the page to ignore the error as you said, the error really dissapeared. This is happens in a local file which is linked then to the iFrame, but the streaming won't play, it seems like it's protected from this kind of things. Do you have any idea? The streamer.php file: http://prntscr.com/rt59dh, the result: http://prntscr.com/rt5b73

Comment: If you call player.twitch.tv in your dev console you'll see a lot of scripts running. so place window.onerror first and how to embed see here: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/embed/video-and-clips

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand. After embedding the live channel, what should I do? How can I ignore the errors from my main page?

Answer (score 0):

Use

WebBrowser1.ScriptsErrorsSuppressed  = true ;

WebBrowser1 os the name oficial WebBrowser control